# Why does the same code I write using vim not work when I write it in the TextEdit application?

Tags: ruby, vim

If I write a simple function like this using vim

```
def hello
  "Hello!"
end
```

and run it, it works fine.

If I create a blank `.rb` file using vim, but then open it with TextEdit and write the exact same thing

```
def hello
  "Hello!"
end
```

I get this issue

```
undefined local variable or method `”' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007f9f64043548>
```

I have tried it with other functions as well, and I still get an issue (although its a different one).

In addition, if I open the blank `.rb` file, and do a copy/paste of the same code from elsewhere and then run, it works ok again.  It's only if I manually type something using the TextEdit application.

Comment: What operating system are you working on? It's possibly something related to how line-endings are encoded (DOS vs. Unix vs. Mac).

Comment: This looks related to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit based on the exception pointing to the curly-quote

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`”` and `"` are different characters. The first is the one in your error message, the second is the correct double quote you need to use.

TextEdit is using fancy quotes, replacing the double quote with right and left quotes. You need to turn that off.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue.  For anyone wondering in the future, just go to System preferences  -- Keyboard -- Text and uncheck "Use smart quotes and dashes"